# Include CMS in .Net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, content-management-system

We are looking for creating a .net MVC web platform that should get some content from a CMS.
We would like to work with Content API, or any other CMS. The most important is that the CMS only should provide content and not be the foundation of our web platform. CMS is only one service of several.

One service we were looking at is [contentful](http://www.contentful.com) or as CMS, [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net).

Several things we are thinking about:

- How to handle Routing?
- How to dynamic requesting the right information based on a certain url?
- If a Content API are handling site structure, how should be handled in our routing?

Regards,
Robert

Comment: I'm not sure you have a full grasp over what it is you need.  Contentful and Orchard are entirely different concepts, for instance.  Contentful is more about managing assets, like images, scripts, and defining types of data... a CMS does those things as well, but also deals with page layout, security, components, etc..

Comment: One option would be to use Contentful as my "asset manager" to manage pages/products/media. But then we need to build the web platform by ourselves, which is in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

Contentful is the way to go imho, https://github.com/JTtheGeek/ContentfulDotNet

You don't need to modify your routing or anything, just pull your data in using this api in a controller via action.